# RobotFramework: "Select Frame" in AppiumLibrary

Tags: robotframework

Is there a AppiumLibrary keyword equivalent to Selenium2Library's `Select Frame`? If not, can anyone recommend an alternative way to select IFRAMEs from a Robot test case?

Comment: Have you read the appium documentation? It seems reasonable to think if it doesn't mention one, there isn't one.

Comment: Yes, there is no such method in Appium. I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: I've gotten stuck on this as well. I noticed that you can only use the webdriver.io/webdriver javascript if the context is WebView, else that will not be an option either.

Answer (score 0):

Bring back the missing keywords from Selenium2Library to AppiumLibrary.
It based on AppiumLibrary and use active library instance to enhance robotframework-appiumlibrary.

https://github.com/ScenK/robotframework-AppiumEnhanceLibrary